# Prime Numbers in Discrete Log

Tags: prime-numbers, discrete-logarithm, number-theory

I am implementing a security protocol based on discrete log. I came across the equation $p = kq + 1$. Understand that based on number theories that both $p$ and $q$ should be large enough to be "safe". However, how does it justifies safe? Say I chose $p = 7$, $k = 2$ and $q = 3$, will my implementation be screwed up?

Comment: You have chosen the tag "dsa", but there is no mention of digital signatures in your question. Do you need primes for Diffie-Hellman or for a signature scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already exist standard primes that might be used for Finite Field Discrete Logarithm based schemes. One set is found in [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526). Another set is currently in the process of being standardized as part of TLS and can be found in [the current Negotiated FF DHE draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-negotiated-ff-dhe-05) (this link will expire no later than June 15 2015).

The smallest prime in the former set is 1536 bits, which means that it is greater than $2^{1535}$. It is recommended to be used with a 180 bit exponent, which corresponds to an integer greater than $2^{179}$.

The smallest prime in the latter set (TLS) is currently fixed at 2048 bits, although an even greater number was originally proposed.

By comparison, 7 is only 3 bits and 3 is only 2 bits, so, yes, your implementation would be kind of inadequate, should you try to use these primes.

Comment: Hi @Henrick Hellström, Thanks for giving such detailed explanation and also providing relevant resource for my learning. Yes, what i am implementing is Chameleon Hashing, which is based on discrete log, like DSA, which I will be using to generate the prime numbers, hence the tag.